# When accessing WordPress through BrowserSync using the external url, it redirects to localhost

Tags: wordpress, gulp-browser-sync

I am working on a WordPress site from my local system and using Gulp with Browsersync to automatically refresh my browser on changes. For this I am using a proxy to my local Apache server.

This works fine from my local machine, but when I try to access the site from the external url I have an issue. I am able to access the homepage just fine through the external url but when I then click on any link it redirects to localhost even though the href points to the external url.

I know that WordPress always provides the full url and this can cause a link to bypass browsersync but to ensure this doesn't happen I have configured WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL to point to port 3000, which BrowserSync listens to.

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://flare-dev.local:3000' );
define('WP_SITEURL','http://flare-dev.local:3000' );
```

Here is my browsersync setup:
Relevant sections in gulpfile.js

```
var browserSync = require( 'browser-sync' ).create();
var cfg = require( './gulpconfig.json' );
gulp.task( 'browser-sync', function() {
  browserSync.init( cfg.browserSyncWatchFiles, cfg.browserSyncOptions );
} );
```

Relevant sections in gulpconfig.json:

```
  "browserSyncOptions" : {
    "proxy": {
      "target": "localhost:80/"
    },
    "notify": false,
    "open": false,
    "host": "flare-dev.local",
    "port": 3000
  },
  "browserSyncWatchFiles" : [
    "./css/*.min.css",
    "./js/*.min.js",
    "./**/*.php"
  ]
```

I've tried multiple different settings in BrowserSyncOptions for proxy, middleware and rewriteRules but nothing changes this behaviour. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably You are running on localhost:80 and you are not using correct proxy url.
Dont write localhost:80/yoursite instead write localhost/yoursite only

```
browserSync.init({
        proxy: {
            target: "http://localhost/yoursite/"
        }
});

Rest you know, use reload with gulp.watch.

export const reload = (done) => {
    browserSync.reload();
    done();
}
```

Rest you know, use reload with gulp.watch.
e.g.
`gulp.watch('**/*.php', reload);`

Comment: The cause of OP's problem has nothing to do with the proxy settings but how Wordpress reference some of its assets (via full URL instead of relative links).

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing this problem because Wordpress reference stylesheets and some other files via full URL like http://localhost:80/wp-content/theme/some.css and these requests are made outside of the BrowserSync's proxy (i.e. http://localhost:3000/wp-content/theme/some.css).

To fix this, you will need to ask BrowserSync to rewrite these links using [rewriteRules](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options#option-rewriteRules).

The following will rewrite all localhost:80 to localhost:3000, forcing all traffic to go through BroswerSync instead of Apache directly.

```
rewriteRules: [
    {
        match: /localhost:80/g,
        fn: function (req, res, match) {
            return 'localhost:3000';
        }
    }
]
```

PS: Having the right proxy settings as suggested by the other answer here is also essential.

```
proxy: {
    target: "http://localhost/yoursite/"
}
```

Please also note that since the rewrite function is a Javascript and not a JSON object, you will need to have it outside of `gulpconfig.json`. You will need to merge it directly in `gulpfile.js`. Instead of:

```
browserSync.init( cfg.browserSyncWatchFiles, cfg.browserSyncOptions );
```

You will need something like

```
browserSync.init(
    cfg.browserSyncWatchFiles, 
    Object.assign(
        cfg.browserSyncOptions, {
            rewriteRules: [
                {
                    match: /localhost:80/g,
                    fn: function (req, res, match) {
                         return 'localhost:3000';
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ) 
 );
```